# Finding a trendline for a set of stock data python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, math

I have 1000+ text files, each with two columns, the first being Dates, the second being prices (for the respective stock). I am looking to find a way to figure out which stocks are trending upwards, downwards, or sideways. I imagine this would require creating a trend line for each file and then finding the slope of that trendline, but my math isn't strong(yet) so I'm not sure. 
So far I have the following code:

```
filelist = os.listdir(r'InsertFilePath')
filepath = r'InsertFilePath'

dic1 = {}

for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath + file,sep='\t')
    dic1[file]= df

#changes the column headers to string 'Dates' and 'Prices'
for key,value in dic1.items():
    value.rename(columns={value.columns[0]:'Dates',value.columns[1]:'Prices'},inplace=True)
```

So essentially I have a dictionary with the DataFrame for each stock as the values and the stock ticker(the file name) as the key.

I have tried this:

```
lst1=[]
lst2=[]
for key,value in dic1.items():
lst1.append([key,value['Prices']])
lst2.append([key,value['Dates']])

sns.lmplot(x=lst2,y=lst1,data=dic1,fit_reg=True)
```

But that gives me errors, and I've played with it a lot.

So my questions are, How can I find a trendline for a dictionary of Dataframes with Dates being the first column and Prices being the second (perhaps I have to set the dates as the index)? How can I figure out the slope of those lines to figure out which way each stock is trending?

Thank you.